# Performance implications for overriding CSS styles

Tags: css, performance, browser

I'm setting up an image cluster for a webpage (similar to sprite-map) for performance reasons. I have a utility that generates the master image, and css to reference the image map.

For simplicity sake, I'd rather include the new css after the regular css file, instead of writing a script to search and replace all the classes in the original css. Something like so in the html (psuedo code):

```
<LINK href="normal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

if(%=usingImageCluster=%)
      <LINK href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So all the styles that are defined in normal.css would get overridden by the new styles in master.css.

Couple of questions:

- Besides the "duplication" of information, does this override cause performance issues?
- Will the browser still pull the non-clustered images, because the original CSS file is still included (negating the positive performance gains of image clustering)?
- Is there a guarantee that the last loaded style will always be the one applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Besides the "duplication" of information, does this override cause performance issues?

Yes, you are generating a new HTTP request for the second external stylesheet.  Too many HTTP requests is the #1 slowdown factor for most webpages.

> Will the browser still pull the non-clustered images, because the original CSS file is still included (negating the positive performance gains of image clustering)?

Yes, the browser will pull *ALL* images from the first and second CSS file.  Performance time will increase almost linearly (approximate).  Especially if you are rewriting every css selector, or changing lots of images.

> Is there a guarantee that the last loaded style will always be the one applied?

Yes.  Unless the first sheet uses `!important` on certain style attributes, the last declared styles for a selector will always be applied.  This is where Cascading Style Sheets get their name.